# Как я могу использовать gulp и npm в работе c CMS? (Друпал)

Tags: gulp, drupal, npm

Наверное вы поняли, что проблема в шаблонах, можно собрать лендосик с индексом хтмл у себя на компе, другое дело работа с кучей шаблонов друпала (либо других CMS) на сервере

Answer (score 0):

Например, обрабатывать sass, js, картинки.
Пишете свой gulp-file в корне темы, и в путь.

Comment: если сервер на своем компе, я понял.
А если через фтп, как командную строку там запустить?

Comment: Тут понятное дело:
- нужен сервер с поддержкой nmp
- или свой настроенный vds
- или обрабатывать локально, а на сервер только выгружать

Comment: на сервере npm не нужен. Создаете проект локально, разрабатываете. На выходе полученный css отправляете по ftp на сервер. Только таким образом.